# How can position auto adjusting html block elements with css in this way (photo attached)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create this page layout with css alone? if so what is the best way to go about it? floating puts all block level elements aligned to the last page break along the top,  display:inline-block just aligns up along the bottom. Neither create the alineation model from the image below.

I know I could position them manually but the divs are filled with content from a data base so they will need to adjust automatically and align this way independently of their size. I thought about calculating all their heights with javascript and positioning them dynamically this way, but I've got this feeling that there might be a simple way of doing this that I'm totally overlooking. any ideas?[image]

Comment: Please clarify how the elements are loaded. Is it just a stack of divs? Your question asks for CSS, yet you have a JavaScript tag.

Comment: In essence it's just a stack of divs but each div is generated dynamically (echoed to the page from php) depending if a catagory exists in a DB then the div is filled with catagory items, so it will vary in size. I added the javascript tag becuase if It's not possible with css then I'm open to Js ideas of how to do this. I would be happy to hear javascript solutions to this question but only as a fall back from css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated response:**

Flexbox almost does what you want (as does something like I posted below) but if you're ordering must be left-to-right and it must tight-fit vertically as in your mock - perhaps consdier something like http://masonry.desandro.com/?

**Original response:**

Maybe try something like this?

```
.container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 15px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/rrpg58yy/

Comment: This implementation orders the elements vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: My apologies. I should have read more carefully. You're right it does. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. That flex box looks interesting and seems somewhat similar to how I envisioned a js solution to be. Your css approach seems to be what I am looking for , It seems obvious now as @rao pointed too.

Comment: No problem :) Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for a layout similar to [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/), so the first Google search returned [this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout). There are a lot of other results, so I am sure one should fit your needs if you search yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have 3 columns, and fill the blocks in them, 
Something like this,

**Skeleton:**

```
<div class="column-container">
  <div class="column-1">
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-3">
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
    <div class="block">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3{
  float:left;
  width:200px; 
  height:auto;
}
.block{
  display:block;
  width:180px;
}
```

And the blocks you add to each column will go sit below one another. Simple.

Comment: Boom there it is , three colomns , like a slap in the face , how obvious . thanks!

Comment: Yep, arranging varying height blocks sounds complex, but the implementation is dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is the one I recommend, u simply add the reference to your file (or project) and then it's really easy to design the layout that you want, after you implement Bootstrap, your code will look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div>some data 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>some data 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>some data 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">....
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4830/)

Make sure you resize your page, since bootstrap stacks all the divs together for smaller (mobile) screens